# Creation of Firewall rule during installation: netsh or WindowsFirewall API?

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-firewall

I'm building an installer for our program here, and I would like to add a firewall rule upon installation.
I've researched a bit and there are 2 approaches I've found:

1. Running a netsh command
2. Programmaticaly with the firewall API

Regarding netsh- there are 2 types of commands documented-

- "netsh firewall add allowedprogram C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe "My
  Application" ENABLE",

  and-
- "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Application" dir=in
  action=allow program="C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe" enable=yes"

..which operating system(s) support which? I guess I could just run both just to be sure
(I would like to support xp,vista and win7)

Regarding the firewallAPI- are there any benefits to using it? It seems a bit more complicated on the surface (I'll need to find out which OS I'm running on for starters, since I will need to connect to a different dll in vista).

Comment: I've ended up using: "netsh firewall add allowedprogram "c\Path.." ApplicationName ENABLE". Don't forget the quotes around the path. This will work in both winXP and win7.

Answer (score 1):

If your simply checking to see if the Firewall is enabled; you could do:

```
NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false);
INetFwMgr Manage = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
bool Firewallenabled = Manage.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;
```

Then you could add your application to the authorized applications;

```
INetFwAuthorizedApplications applications;
INetFwAuthorizedApplication application;

// Input Application Name
application.Name = “Internet Explorer”;

// Locate .exe
 application.ProcessImageFileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"

// Enable
application.Enabled =  true; 

// Authorize the Application
Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
         INetFwMgr Manage = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType); 
         applications = (INetFwAuthorizedApplications)mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications;
applications.Add(application);
```

You'll need access to these COM Objects:

- *NetFwTypeLib*
- *HNetCfg.FwMgr*

Keep in mind that these are written with older COM objects for XP SP2; where Microsoft suggest you use: *INetFwPolicy2*. It will work though for Vista, 7, and 8.  Here is some documentation including the article with several examples using the older code; don't know if this helps.  Hopefully it does.

[Vista, 7, 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366418%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[XP Service Pack 2:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366453%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Blog with those examples in detail; and explanations.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx)